Is Multipoint Bluetooth supported on Ubuntu 24.04?
My earbuds (Pixel buds pro) support multipoint, and I can connect them to both my Ubuntu 24.04 machine and my phone. However, if I'm playing audio on Ubuntu, and then play audio on the phone (call, video, etc...) the audio I was playing on Ubuntu continues (i.e. the track progresses) but with no audio.
When I'm done with the audio on the phone, Ubuntu doesn't resume playing the audio on the earbuds.
Is that supported, and if so, what do I need to do to enable it?
